# Setting up TypeScript for node by using module=system is not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, systemjs

I tried to setup a restify project using typescript.
After various tries I was able to create a working version by using "module: commonjs" in the tsconfig.json

I'd prefer to use system - but I wasn't able to set it up with systemjs

**boot.ts**

```
import {AppServer} from './app';

var _appServer = new AppServer();
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**app.ts**

```
/// <reference path="typings/restify/restify.d.ts" />
import {Server, Response, Request, createServer} from 'restify';

export class AppServer {

  private server: Server;

  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.server = createServer();
    this.server.get('/hello/:name', this.respond);

    this.server.listen(8080, () => {
      console.log('%s listening at %s', this.server.name, this.server.url);
    });
  }

  respond(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
    res.send('hello ' + req.params.name);
    next();
  }

}
```

using
`"module": "system"`
in the tsconfig.json, I get the following output (even with `import System = require('systemjs')`in the boot.ts):

```
➜  server git:(master) ✗ npm run server                                                        

> server@1.0.0 server /Users/maquh/Development/02_Backgular/server
> node boot.js

/Users/maquh/Development/02_Backgular/server/boot.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { System.register(['./app'], function(exports_1) {
                                                              ^

ReferenceError: System is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/maquh/Development/02_Backgular/server/boot.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
    at startup (node.js:138:18)
    at node.js:974:3
```

**Transpiled boot.js**

```
System.register(['./app'], function(exports_1) {
    var app_1;
    var _appServer;
    return {
        setters:[
            function (app_1_1) {
                app_1 = app_1_1;
            }],
        execute: function() {
            //System.import('./app.ts').
            _appServer = new app_1.AppServer();
        }
    }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=boot.js.map
```

UPDATE:
I also tried another alternative version of **boot.ts**

```
var System = require('systemjs');

System.transpiler = 'ts';


System.import('./app.js').then(function(m) {
  console.log(m);
}, function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

those leads to the following error:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/markusbellgardt/Development/02_Backgular/server/restify']
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? How do you know you were not able?

Comment: Added terminal output

Comment: you are showing `boot.ts`, which doesn't appear to have the line that appears to be crashing from `boot.js`.  can you show the disk contents (compiled output) of `boot.js`?

Comment: did you try doing this: `global.System = require('systemjs');` in boot.ts?

Comment: I tried to do this (it seems similar to define global.ts stated on https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs ) but the error is still the same.
I think the main problem is, that the `"module": "system"` in the tsconfig.json wich always adds those System.register before I'm able to declare what System is.

Comment: Right. In that case you'll need a js entry file. Just create a new js file, add that line and add `require('./boot.js');`.

Comment: Adding a new file (run.js) did also not work:
`/Users/maquh/Development/02_Backgular/server/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:2777
          throw new TypeError('Unexpected anonymous System.register call.');`

I also tried the following **boot.ts**:
`var System = require('systemjs');

 System.transpiler = 'ts';

 System.import('./app.js').then(function(m) {
   console.log(m);
 }, function(err) {
   console.error(err);
 });`
Error: `[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/maquh/Development/02_Backgular/server/restify']`

Answer (score 2):

System uses ES6 module loaders which nodejs (to my knowledge) does not currently support, your initial use case was right where you were outputting to `commonjs`. If you want to use the ES6 style module resolution within node you will need to tell node how to load it such as:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-module-loader

I use typescript in node fine but I use `commonjs`, I have used `system` in the browser before and it works fine when you have ES6 module loaders available such as SystemJs (JSPM).